# SQL Server : BULK INSERT fails

Tags: sql-server

I have generated a tab delimited data file from MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE, and now I'm trying to use this file to insert the data into SQL Server; however, I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 8 (key_version).

I'm guessing the cause is the line termination because if the file contains only one record, the `BULK INSERT` in SQL Server works. I tried generating the data file with

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

as well as `'\n\r'` and both return the same error.

The MySQL query to generate the tab delimited data file is:

```
SELECT _id, event_timestamp, door_id, building_id, scanner_ip, key_id, key_name, key_version 
INTO OUTFILE 'B:/tmp/log_access_02.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM log_access;
```

The table structure in SQL Server is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log_access]
(
    [_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [event_datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [door_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [building_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [scanner_ip] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [key_id] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [key_name] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [key_version] [varchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_log_access] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([_id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[log_access] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_event_event_datetime]  
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [event_datetime]
GO
```

The bulk insert query is:

```
BULK INSERT log_video_plays
FROM 'C:\share\log_access_02.txt'
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
   ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

And a sample of the tab delimited data file:

```
1353097539  2014-09-10 00:00:00 1   2   192.168.1.4 a0074895532256BCDA40EF1536E08BC7628a    ABFGKLP-BRASR_v12   2.35.538.11353097540    2014-09-10 00:00:00 1   2   192.168.1.35    x0074893552256454A40EF1536E08BC7628x    ABFGKLP-BRASR_v12   2.35.538.1
```

Comment: do you have column names in first row of your file by any chance ?

Comment: No, the file does not include column names; it consists of data only.

Comment: Can `ROWTERMINATOR` be `\r\n` instead of a single `\n`? You mentioned trying `\n\r`, but not `\r\n` (Windows line terminator).

Comment: I have tried both \r\n and \n as the ROWTERMINATOR

Comment: Your sample data has nothing between records one and two, so field 8 is run-on. (and the tabs are space-converted, but that's probably due to C&P foofaraw)

Comment: I have posted the generated file on http://expirebox.com/download/41ed27db15e5b7e833070972cf7dc171.html

Comment: I think I've figured it out... On MySQL side the data file needs to be generated with '\r\n' and on the SQL Server side do not use ROWTERMINATOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use other line termination sequences such as \n\r (e.g. from RISC OS), \r (e.g. Mac OS 9), \n (most *nix systems, including OS X) and \r\n (Windows). try it first...

```
BULK
INSERT log_video_plays
FROM 'C:\share\log_access_02.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
,ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
);
```

Comment: I also had to change the MySQL query to use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'.